# How to display a list of items in the shape of bootstrap cards class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I've been searching for a while on how to custom a list of items in asp.net mvc

and then i was thinking if it is possible to use "Cards Class" from "Bootstrap" to display a list of items on it.

I want something like that :

```
<div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card-header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleTitle)</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleText)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticlePostDate)</p>
</div>
```

The purpose is to display a list with the style of bootstrap cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap class with a list or normal display data I wrote an example about this issue my c# codes like this. Also you can give all razor item css more detail https://www.telerik.com/blogs/stay-sharp-razor-taghelpers

```
public IActionResult Index()
   {
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            var u = new User() {
                ID = 1,
                Name ="a",
                Surname="aa",
                Number=111
            };

            var u2 = new User()
            {
                ID = 2,
                Name = "b",
                Surname = "bb",
                Number = 111
            };
            var u3 = new User()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "a",
                Surname = "aa",
                Number = 111
            };
            users.Add(u);
            users.Add(u2);
            users.Add(u3);

            return View(users);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var uu = new User()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "a",
                Surname = "aa",
                Number = 111
            };
            ViewBag.User = uu;
            return View();
            }
}
}
```

User list with you card css like this.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.User>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h1>List Sample</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
            <div class="card-header">@item.Name</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">@item.Surname</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p class="card-text">@item.Number</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and show only one daya like this

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
<div>
    <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
        <div class="card-header">@ViewBag.User.Name</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">@ViewBag.User.Surname</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text">@ViewBag.User.Number</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```